# Difficulty writing content of Array into tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I've been struggling to complete a task which involves taking values from json (from a link), write it to an array, then insert it in my row by saying

```
cell.textLabel.text=[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

get method

```
-(void)getData:(NSData *) responseData{
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData option:kNilOptions error:&error[;
myArray=[json objectForKey:@"cars"];
NSLog(@"cars %@",myArray);//returns array values just fine
}
```

The **NSLog** about returns my array perfectly, 
however when i say

```
cell.textLabel.text=[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

it is null, (which i think is because this code runs before the getData method BUT even if I write out the URL to an array IN the load method and log it there and get my array, when i try to assign it to a cell, i get null again.
Would really love if I would be able to fix this. Thank you
added code

Editted: Added code, previous issue solved but now trying to get the values of TypesArray(dictionary) to show in my cell label. or should i just get the JSon into Array format. 
Json Data is `{"regions":{"region":"House"}` but doesnt let me format as a Array

```
 #define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)
    #define kmyURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.site.com/region/index.php"]

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 

    [super viewDidLoad];
  NSURL *myURL =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.site.com/region/index.php"];

    NSError *error=nil;
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
  //  sqlResults=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kmyURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject: data  waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}


-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData{

    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    myarr=[json valueForKey:@"regions"];
    NSLog(@"regions: %@",myarr);
    TypesArray =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:json];
    NSLog(@"json %@",TypesArray);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    NSLog(@"Sql Results: %@",sqlResults);
      NSLog(@"regions out: %@",myarr);
    NSLog(@"Typesb: %@",TypesArray);

    cell.textLabel.text=[TypesArray valueForKey:@"region"]; //Nothing is being written to cell here
return cell;
}
```

Data Looks like this:

```
{"regions":{"region":"Island"}}
```

Comment: you array myArray should be strong. change its property attribute to strong.

Comment: You should also be calling `reloadData` in `getData:`

Comment: Your use of `objectForKey:` should also be `valueForKey:` by the looks of it

Comment: @Wain pretty much tried all the offered solutions but to no avail ( reload data actually throws san error on my cell.textlabel.text line )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused with `NSArray` functions and `NSDictionary` functions.

```
valueForKey:
```

Returns an array of values, by going to each object of the array and requesting a value for the key specified. This is very clearly explained in the code docs (Code completion even shows a more button with a link to it).

You have not posted a sample of your data or whether `TypesArray` is an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary` (Please note variables should not have a capital letter at the start).

If it is a `NSDictionary` use this:

```
[TypesArray objectForKey:@"region"];
```

if it is an array of `NSDictionary`'s

```
[[TypesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"region"];
```

For the above, note it doesn't matter whether you define it as an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. It Matters whats returned from the webservice call. Use `[ class]` and `[ isKindOfClass:]` to check this.

Please in future post all the code containing object definitions and samples of the data, anywhere you say "Prints out X", please show the print out to us. Finally you said you printed out the dictionary, that went fine, but getting a value isn't updating the label, print out the value your trying to get also, and again show us. We can't make guesses on this stuff, thats why nobody was able to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help an brief explanation. I had created TypesArray as an NSDictionary in the .h file. however  objectForKey didnt work so someone suggested that I Use value, also NSDictionary doesnt respond to objectAtIndex. ( I updated my main code with the format and also my JSON from my link- was thinking to make this easier shouldnt I just redo my JSON so it can be assigned an Array )

Comment: @SleepParalysis Again `{"regions":{"region":"Island"}}`  is a dictionary inside a dictionary, you need to study up on how JSON maps to objective-c objects. ValueForKey is looking for "region" at the same level "regions" is at. Try this: `[[TypesArray objectForKey:@"regions"] objectForKey:@"region"];`

Comment: {"regions":{"region":"Island"}} if regions is a dictionary in a dictionary. is it safe to call [{"regions":{"region":"Island"}}] a dict, inside a dict, inside an array?

Comment: @SleepParalysis Yes. `{"region":"Island"}` is a dictionary with a single key / value. `{"regions":{"region":"Island"}}` is a dictionary with a single key, the value of which is the previous dictionary. `[{"regions":{"region":"Island"}}]` is an array with a single entry, the entry being the previous dictionary

Comment: i said `cell.textLabel.text=[[[TypesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"regions"]objectForKey:@"region"];`
And it works! thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several major issues with your code.

First, you use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` to get data from a link that is not local. Even doing it in a background thread is a bad idea. From the [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL%3a):

> Important: Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based
>   URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread
>   for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user
>   experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated. Instead,
>   for non-file URLs, consider using the
>   dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler: method of the NSSession class. See
>   URL Loading System Programming Guide for details.

Your overall threading is a mess. I would recommend using the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) framework to simplify the threading. This would allow you to remove all the threading logic from the code you show.

Next, it appears that your `NSArray` is an array of `NSDictionary` objects. You probably need to change your label text assignment to:

```
cell.textLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row][@"car"];
```

Comment: I was aware my threading was not the neatest (btw thanks for the link.) but this is not even the code I originally had, I just kept morphing it to try to solve this issue. But btw it did not work

Comment: "Did not work," is not helpful. What did it do that you did not expect? What was your expectation that it did not perform?

Comment: was expecting the leftview to show the value of car array but it's not

Answer (score 1):

First of all once you get data , reload the tableview

```
-(void)getData:(NSData *) responseData
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData option:kNilOptions error:&error[;
    myArray=[json objectForKey:@"cars"];
    NSLog(@"cars %@",myArray);

    //here reload the table
    [yourTableObject reloadData];
}
```

And for assigning data from array to table cell use following

```
cell.textLabel.text =[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"car"];
```

Comment: @Simon McLoughlin I am saying [self.tableview reloadData]; (tableview being the leftviewcontroller but i am getting a bad access error on cell.textLabel.text line. Secondly. nslog is showing me that myArray is still null when that line is called (guess thats why we need reloadData right?)

Comment: @SleepParalysis I only edited the code format of this answer. Looking at your question now, your missing a huge amount of necessary code. Don't post a line like this `cell.textLabel.text=[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` Show us the full file, where the array is defined, where the data is passed and the callback for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin added the rest of the code in main questio

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin hi, I actually got a bit more to work and i believe i am almost at the end,  1 final thing is getting the data to show in cell.textlabel.text i tried   cell.textLabel.text=[TypesArray valueForKey:@"region"]; (and object) but said cell is still blank but NSLog shows me data in the dictinary and objectAtIndex dont work with Dictionaries

Comment: @SleepParalysis I supplied my own answer, please check it out

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

```
 NSError * deserializationError = nil;
 CJSONDeserializer *deserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
 NSDictionary *dict = [deserializer deserialize:conn error:&deserializationError];
 NSDictionary * response = [dict objectForKey:@"cars"];

 ArrayCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[response count]];

 for (int index = 0; index < [response count]; index--) {
       NSMutableDictionary * value = [response objectAtIndex:index];
       CustomCell *cell = [[CustomCell alloc] init];
       cell.car = [value objectForKey:@"car"];
       [ArrayCells addObject:cell];
 }
```

and:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        return [ArrayCells objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
 }
```

or something like that....

Good luck!

Comment: the first code block you posted would go in fetchData?

Comment: Yes,     NSError * reqError = nil;
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSData *conn = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&reqError];